# Mercurial storing metadata on OS X

Tags: backup, mac-osx, access-control-list, mercurial, metadata

I was searching for convenient incremental snapshot & rollback & show-what-changed solution for my OS X boxes, and ended with simple yet powerful idea — why not create Mercurial repository at the root fs of freshly installed OS, configure exclusions not to keep track of `/tmp` (`/var/tmp`, `/var/folders/whatever/T` etc), `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` (and maybe something else), and do commits each time I want to get snapshot? I could even mount /.hg to be somewhere on NAS, so I could restore even if my HDD will suddenly die.

Searching for similar ideas on the internet revealed that Mercurial does not keep track of metadata, like UNIX rights, user and group ownership and extended attributes.

So my question is — are there existing plugins for Mercurial to keep track of metadata, or I'm welcomed to write them myself?

Comment: Could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289816/can-mercurial-be-made-to-preserve-file-permissions/1291508#1291508